# Jenkins builds and queue management

Tags: regex, groovy, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm trying to improve our queue manager, and what I'd like to do is this:

There are two types triggers that can start a job (in this case regular, and upstream). If in the queue, there is ever a regular build and an upstream build, the upstream job will always execute, and we cancel the regular build. And if there are ever multiple instances with the same trigger (for the same job), we always take the first one, and cancel the rest, we don't want duplicate jobs in the queue.

These are triggers for the same job, and has nothing to do with concurrency of other jobs!

How can I achieve this? Using groovy, how can I get a list of triggers for the job and apply the logic I described above? Is there a plugin that'll solve my problem?

new to groovy, and jenkins, so maybe I'm trying to re-invent the wheel here

Answer (score 1):

It might not do exactly what you want, but take a look at the [Accelerated Build Now](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Accelerated+Build+Now+Plugin) plugin in combination with the [Priority Sorter](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Priority+Sorter+Plugin) plugin

Comment: ended up using the Priority Sorter plugin. With some additional tweaks added on my end.